# hyper-v rollback with login error: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: windows, dns, hyper-v

Today I try to rollback one hyperV vm which is domain joined.

When it is rolled back and started, it displays following error:

> The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain
>   failed.

I tried solution to log off domain and rejoin domain. It throws following error:

> "computer name is already existing in domain"

I also tried solution from following post:
http://implbits.com/About/Blog/tabid/78/post/don-t-rejoin-to-fix-the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain-failed/Default.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325850

with command to sync account password:

```
netdom resetpwd /s:server /ud:domain\User /pd:*
```

Throws following mesage:

> The machine account password for the local machine could not be reset.
>
> Access is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last the issue is fixed by:
1.Export target vm snapshot
2.Import exported snapshot
3.Log in to new vm and unregister from domain
4.Rename vm computer name
5.Rejoin to domain

But I do not think it is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue running a windows 10 guest on a Windows 10 HyperV. The following fixed it.

Logon to the VM using a local admin account and run powershell and execute

> Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server **[MyDomainController]** -Credential
>   **[MyDomain\administrator]**